# Creates some audio process like Voice Changer or framework of iZotope

Tags: ios, core-audio, openal

I'm working on audio filter job on iOS.

It's quiet tough.

I want to make 'Object' includes AudioSession that make audio DSP using exist audio.

So, I made some DSP filters on my note but,

I cannot know how can I bring the existing audio file to the session

and how apply filters on it.

Your every hints will be granted.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For filtering mic input, look at Apple's documentation and sample apps regarding the Audio Queue and Audio Unit APIs.